# Using variable to affect my position

Tags: java

I am making a unit move in my game by using simple method like: getting the position north of this position. But I want different units with different speeds and I am a bit confused as how to do this.
Position class:

```
public class Position {
private int x;
private int y;

public Position(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public Position getPosToNorth() {
    Position position = new Position(getX(), getY() - 1);
    return position;
}
}
```

And then in my other class I got this move method:

```
public void move()
{
    if(this.direction == "North")
    {           
        setPosition(getPosition().getPosToNorth());
    }
}
```

If I have a variable, let's say: speed = 10; how can I use this to affect how much my unit will move? Can I somehow get the speed variable from my other class into my Position class so instead of taking getY() - 1 it takes getY() - speed? I tried but didn't get it to work... thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can, add getter of speed in that class and call it from Position if speed is not constant. If speed is always same, make public final variable in that class/or may be in Position class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simplest solution would be something like this.
change the getPosToNorth like this:

```
public Position getPosToNorth(int speed) {
    Position position = new Position(getX(), getY() - speed);
    return position;
}
```

in your move now do this:

```
public void move()
{
    if(this.direction == "North")
    {           
        setPosition(getPosition().getPosToNorth(this.speed));
    }
}
```

so you store the speed in your `this` object and you pass it to the `getPosToNorth`method

btw. use `equals()` to compare Strings:

```
if(this.direction.equals("North"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on how your world is defined:

- Are there discrete positions like tiles? I assume yes, since you're using integer coordinates.
- Are units allowed to move diagonally? If yes, that complicates things a bit.

Basically, you'd just calculate the new position based on the current coordinates and add/subtract speed (however that is defined in your case) accordingly.

I'd do something like this:

```
enum Direction {
  NORTH( 0, -1),
  SOUTH( 0, 1 ),
  EAST( 1, 0).
  WEST( -1, 0);
  int x;
  int y;

  //constructor and getters
}  

Position move(Direction dir, int speed) {
  return new Position(x + dir.getX() * speed, y + dir.getY() * speed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new field in position class called speed and corresponding getter and setter like below:

```
int speed;
public int getSpeed() {return speed;}    
public void setSpeed(int speed) {this.speed = speed;}
```

And in your getPosToNorth method you could do:

```
public Position getPosToNorth() {
    Position position = new Position(getX(), getY() - getSpeed());//set the speed before calling this method
    return position;
}
```

or if you get the speed in class where you have move method then change the signature of getPosToNorth to include the speed as well like below:

```
public Position getPosToNorth(int speed) {
    Position position = new Position(getX(), getY() - speed);
    return position;
}
```

and then call it from move method as:

```
setPosition(getPosition().getPosToNorth(1000));//set speed accordingly
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the speed to your method.

```
public Position getPosToNorth(int speed) {
    Position position = new Position(getX(), getY() - speed);
    return position;
}
```

Also since this method is in your own class, you don't have to add getX and getY. Also you don't have to asign your new Position first before you return it. You can return it right away. Just do this:

```
public Position getPosToNorth(int speed) {
    return new Position(this.x, this.y - speed);
}
```

Than you can call this method with:

```
myOwnPositionObject.getPosToNorth(myspeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a parameter in your method?

```
  public Position getPosToNorth(int speed) {
      Position position = new Position(getX(), getY() - speed);
      return position;
  }
```

And the method using it could become

```
public void move()
{
    if(this.direction == "North")
    {           
        setPosition(getPosition().getPosToNorth(this.speed));
    }
}
```

Note that you could also use a speed parameter in `move()`.